# Calculating Standard Deviation from Average and Total Values

Tags: standard-deviation

I'm looking to calculate the standard deviation when all I have is the average alongside how many records there are.

In my dataset I have been provided, I can see an average value which is reflected in the top 5 of the dataset provided.

How can I get the values in between, roughly speaking?

For example, I have an average of £735 in the top 5.

Thanks.

Comment: This is an impossible task. For all we know, the rest could very well be £$0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t.

If I understand correctly, you are given the values of $n$ and $\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nx_k$. It is not possible to recover the individual values of the $x_k$ from this, which are needed to compute the standard deviation.

Comment: Thank you @MPW for the reply, am I not able to get a rough idea of the min, mid and max going by an average value and how many entries there are?

Comment: Nope. Think about $\{-1,1\}$ vs $\{-100,100\}$. They both have the same average and the sam number of points, but one is clearly more widely distributed than the other.

Comment: In fact you can take any two points $x, y$ from your data set and replace them by $x+1000000$ and $y-1000000$ without changing the average or the number of points, but you will have changed the standard deviation.

Comment: Thank you @MPW, so am I able to get a rough estimate, or what other data would I need to obtain in order to get this in the first place?

Comment: If you also had the average of the squared values, you could compute it

Comment: So, I have the number of enquiries a client made, alongside the average price a ticket was offered for by other merchants in the top 5 (as a single figure), would this help to get the price?

E.g. 15 enquiries, with an average merchant price of 3423 (in the top 5 combined). @MPW